# ASP.NET MVC ModelState.IsValid doesnt work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, validation, modelstate

I've this controller's method for create

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Topic topic)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            topicRepo.Add(topic);
            topicRepo.Save();

            return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = topic.ID });
        }
        return View(topic);
    }
```

and this for edit

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection formCollection)
        {
            Topic topic = topicRepo.getTopic(id);
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                UpdateModel<Topic>(topic);
                topicRepo.Save();
                return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = topic.ID });
            }
            return View(topic);
        }
```

Both of these methods use common partial page (.ascx).

Validation works when I try to create topic but  doesn't work when I  try to edit it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's normal. In the first example you are using a model as action parameter. When the default model binder tries to bind this model from the request it will automatically invoke validation and when you enter the action the `ModelState.IsValid` is already assigned.

In the second example your action takes no model, only a key/value collection and without a model validation makes no sense. Validation is triggered by the `UpdateModel<TModel>` method which in your example is invoked **after** the `ModelState.IsValid` call.

So you could try this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    Topic topic = topicRepo.getTopic(id);
    UpdateModel<Topic>(topic);
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        topicRepo.Save();
        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = topic.ID });
    }
    return View(topic);
}
```

Comment: FYI - UpdateModel will throw if ModelState.IsValid is false.  If you don't want it to throw, use TryUpdateModel instead.

Comment: If there are errors, return View(topic) will return values from database to view instead of values from form. And no validatation errors will be displayed.