# MVC3 DataAnnotations ServerSide Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, data-annotations, server-side

So im new to MVC3 and expirimenting with DataAnnotations for the validation.
All is working fine clientside, but how do I get the serverside version working?
If I disable Javascript then there are no validations to be seen.

My Model looks like this

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Verplicht", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof (ValidatieStrings))]
    [Display(Name="Voorletters", ResourceType = typeof (VeldNaamStrings))]
    public string Voorletters { get; set; }
```

My Controller looks like this

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using inschrijven_werknemer.Models;

namespace inschrijven_werknemer.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : LocalizationController
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(new MedewerkInfoModel());
        }
    }
}
```

And my View looks like this

```
@model inschrijven_werknemer.Models.MedewerkInfoModel

<div class="stap-div" id="stap2">
    @Html.EditorForModel("MedewerkInfoModel")
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seems you need to "bind" the Model in order for the DataAnnotations to trigger ServerSideValidation

[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index([Bind]MedewerkInfoModel medewerkInfoModel)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return View(medewerkInfoModel);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do something like this... using `Model.IsValid` property.

So you could try this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(new MedewerkInfoModel());
    }
    return View();
}
```

A more detailed read is available here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5969156/1182982 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/4760494/1182982